# how to protect user data from eachother using typegraphql-prisma

Tags: node.js, authentication, graphql, prisma, typegraphql

I'm building a server based off typegraphql-prisma like here:  https://github.com/prisma/prisma-examples/tree/latest/typescript/graphql-typegraphql-crud

I now have a server where different Users can be created and can have different Posts as per in the example code.  Are there instructions or a path I should take to have each user authenticated and unable to delete each others posts?  Cause now, anyone on my consuming client can delete anyone else's posts.  I see some auth stuff in there but I don't see where to add code during a delete mutation like "if (notOwner) {return null}"  Surely there is a way to auth these types of mutations inside the autogen resolvers through some middle ware or something.

Thanks

Comment: This might have something to do with it but I'll need to review the options: https://github.com/MichalLytek/typegraphql-prisma/discussions/72

Answer (score 4):

MichalLytek gave me the following link which helped me:

https://typegraphql.com/docs/custom-decorators.html

I used that link in combination with the typegraphql-prisma instructions here:

https://prisma.typegraphql.com/docs/advanced/additional-decorators

to make a call like `applyResolversEnhanceMap(resolversEnhanceMap);` before the `buildSchema` and it did the trick. Then I passed in a connected `PrismaClient` to the decorator function to check stuff within the ORM models like my 'Issues' model here:

```
import { validate, ValidationError } from "class-validator";
import {
  ClassType,
  ArgumentValidationError,
  createMethodDecorator,
} from "type-graphql";
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";

// sample implementation of custom validation decorator
// this example use `class-validator` however you can plug-in `joi` or any other lib
export function ValidateDeleteIssueOwnership<T extends object>(
  Type: ClassType<T>,
  prisma: PrismaClient
) {
  return createMethodDecorator(async ({ args, context, info }, next) => {
    const instance = Object.assign(new Type(), args);
    console.log(" instance: ", instance);

    // console.log(' context: ', context);
    // console.log(' info: ', info);

    // const validationErrors = await validate(instance);
    // if (validationErrors.length > 0) {
    //   throw new ArgumentValidationError(validationErrors);
    // }

    const numberIssues = await prisma.issue.count();
    if (numberIssues === 0) {
      throw new Error(
        "CUSTOM DECORATOR - Oh Nos!!!  There were no issues to delete!  "
      );
    }

    return next();
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip... "make a call like applyResolversEnhanceMap(resolversEnhanceMap); **before** the buildSchema and it did the trick." I could't get it to work until I found this question. Thanks a lot

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Casl](https://casl.js.org/v5/en/) for that, it is a library for authorization. You can restrict than just the owner can manage its resources.